# 'class X' has no member 'Y'

Tags: c++

This error is inexplicably occurring. Here is the code and output:

timer.cpp:

```
#include "timer.h"
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_timer.h"

void cTimer::recordCurrentTime()
{
    this->previous_t = this->current_t;
    this->current_t = SDL_GetTicks();
}
```

timer.h:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_timer.h"

class cTimer
{
private:
    int previous_t;
    int current_t;
    float delta_time;
    float accumulated_time;
    int frame_counter;
public:
    void recordCurrentTime();
    float getDelta();
    void incrementAccumulator();
    void decrementAccumulator();
    bool isAccumulatorReady();
    void incrementFrameCounter();
    void resetFrameCounter();
    int getFPS();
};
```

Compiler errors:

```
make
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/SDL -c timer.cpp
timer.cpp: In member function ‘void cTimer::recordCurrentTime()’:
timer.cpp:6: error: ‘class cTimer’ has no member named ‘previous_t’
timer.cpp:6: error: ‘class cTimer’ has no member named ‘current_t’
timer.cpp:7: error: ‘class cTimer’ has no member named ‘current_t’
make: *** [timer.o] Error 1
```

Compiler errors after removing the #include "timer.h"

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/SDL -c ctimer.cpp
ctimer.cpp:4: error: ‘cTimer’ has not been declared
ctimer.cpp: In function ‘void recordCurrentTime()’:
ctimer.cpp:5: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function
ctimer.cpp:5: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function
ctimer.cpp:6: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function
make: *** [ctimer.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I thought you do not need `this->`

Comment: It's a style I like, it explicitly specifies the scope of previous_t and current_t. At any rate, I doubt it has anything to do with his issue.

Comment: @Hamish: You're right, `this` is not needed; it's often avoided, in fact.

Comment: is `cTimer` referring to a static method using `::` notation? In PHP, that's the scope resolution operator and is used for static methods.

Comment: @Anthony: `cTimer` is the name of the class. `::` is a resolution operator in C++, too -- for namespaces and classes. `cTimer::recordCurrentTime` is telling the compiler that this member is found in the `cTimer` class.

Comment: what version of g++ and SDL out of curiosity ?

Comment: I must type awfully slow, lots of people already posted the same response (including me)

Comment: I just resolved it. For whatever reason, a timer.h.gch file was residing in the same directory (I really don't know how it got there). Removing it fixed the error (apparently).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me. Are you sure you've got the right `timer.h`? Try this:

```
cat timer.h
```

and verify that it's what you think it is. If so, try adding `^__^` at the beginning of your `.h` file and seeing if you get a syntax error. It should look something like this:

```
[/tmp]> g++ -Wall -I/tmp/foo -c timer.cpp
In file included from timer.cpp:1:
timer.h:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘^’ token
```

Comment: Yeah, adding ^__^ did nothing. But oddly enough, cat timer.h printed out the exact correct file.

Comment: However, it does seem to be ignoring the timer.h

Comment: rename your timer.h to something like mytimer.h

Comment: John, I just did that, to no effect.

Comment: You we're correct, it was using a timer.h.gch I was unaware of. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to run `make clean` before you build things! :)

Comment: You can also use `-MD` with GCC or  `/showIncludes` with MSVC to help diagnose these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3):

This seems very odd as

```
class cTimer
{
private:
    int previous_t;
    int current_t;
    float delta_time;
    float accumulated_time;
    int frame_counter;
public:
    void recordCurrentTime();
    float getDelta();
    void incrementAccumulator();
    void decrementAccumulator();
    bool isAccumulatorReady();
    void incrementFrameCounter();
    void resetFrameCounter();
    int getFPS();
};
void cTimer::recordCurrentTime()
{
    this->previous_t = this->current_t;
    this->current_t = SDL_GetTicks();
}
```

Compiles OK for me.

This suggests that the compiler think cTimer is different from what you've put in your header. So maybe its getting a definition of cTimer from another source file? For this to be the case your "timer.h" would have to not be gettting included correctly. So maybe the wrong timer.h.

A way to check this would be to save the compiler preprocessor output and search that for cTimer.

Another option might be to put a syntax error in your timer.h and make sure the compile fails.

Anyway hope this helps

Comment: good idea too, but I expect the issue is the include path / which timer.h is being included.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers have their own timer.h, this is a name conflict.

Or it is a something else of bizarre bug...

Comment: mind you that "cTimer is a contraction of "class and Timer" and that is common as you naming a person "John" or a dog as "Rex".

Test naming it like: MyNameClassTimer and see if it fixes. It it does not fix, then try recompiling the entire project from scratch

Comment: Btw: What I mean by "MyName" is really your name, I for example name my classes that have name collision as HMGSomething (HMG are my initials)

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming timer.h and timer.cpp to something more descriptive like ClassTimer.h and ClassTimer.cpp, maybe the compiler is linking another file named 'timer' since it is a very generic name. Also try this in timer.cpp:

```
void cTimer::recordCurrentTime(void)
{
    this->previous_t = this->current_t;
    this->current_t = SDL_GetTicks();
}
```

Edit: code edited

Comment: This won't work for me, it'll just give a 'multiple declaration' error.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of something else in Objective-C... well the edited code works for me. I think you have a name confliction, maybe try using a namespace and a different file name?